# WPF, UWP and Hardware

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, hardware, uwp-xaml

I just got back from Microsoft Build 2018 where they announced .NET Core 3 support for WPF applications. This is great because I can finally start using some of those cool fluent design things that are available for UWP.  The only problem is, it's not getting released until next year.

I started looking into converting my app to a UWP app (because I'm impatient) but I'm running into some challenges.  Mainly hardware.  Talking with a few guys at Build, they made it seem like it was possible to write UWP apps that connect to low-level Win32 drivers for communicating with hardware (HID printers, card readers, bar code scanners, etc).  I'm not having any luck finding information about this.  Just to be clear, this is not an app I want to release to the Windows Store. This is a kiosk app that runs on our own hardware.

How does one access Win32 APIs for hardware integration in UWP?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Mainly just how to access Win32 APIs for hardware in UWP.

Comment: You are mixing it up heavily.  One intended target for UWP is IoT, running on sub-$100 midget hardware.  IoT makes interfacing to hardware important, the Windows.Devices namespace is extensive.  Nothing actually new, but much easier to use than the legacy winapi.  WPF and Winforms support on .NETCore v3 doesn't have anything to do with a UWP target.  Nor is it going to give the DirectX goodies beyond what WPF already supports.

Comment: One of the things they talked about at Build was how WPF targeting .NET Core 3 will bring UWP controls into the WPF and WinForms world.  And even though they didn't announce it, one of the MS guys said WPF isn't far off from getting a DX upgrate once it's able to support core.

Comment: @ChrisLees Have you seen the topic https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/win32-and-com/win32-and-com-for-uwp-apps?

Comment: @BreezeLiu-MSFT is this only for C++ or did Microsoft spell C# wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, similar question here. I guess the downvotes are due not being specific enough wether you want to access hardware from an windows 10 (uwp) app or actually want to run the uwp app on hardware. Anyways, what did you end up doing?

Comment: @CularBytes I gave up and abandoned UWP all together.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is likely to use [P/Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-call-native-dlls-from-managed-code-using-pinvoke), which is technology designed to allow .NET code to call unmanaged code. Assuming that your hardware is accessed through Win32 APIs in a DLL, this may be your best option.

The [pinvoke.net](https://www.pinvoke.net/) Web site provides specific examples of the .NET code needed to call a specific Win32 API. Perhaps those examples can help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

UWP app written in C++/CX has access to the Win32 and COM APIs that are part of the Universal Windows Platform (UWP).
The APIs in [Win32 and COM APIs for UWP apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/win32-and-com/win32-and-com-for-uwp-apps) is only for C++, you can not use the C# to access it directly. Please see [Visual C++ Language Reference (C++/CX)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/visual-c-language-reference-c-cx) to get more details about C++/CX.

But, you can create a Windows Runtime component in C++/CX, then call it from C#, you can see the Walkthrough here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/walkthrough-creating-a-basic-windows-runtime-component-in-cpp-and-calling-it-from-javascript-or-csharp

Comment: I'd rather not learn a new language just to send a few documents to an HID printer. Thank you for the info though!

Comment: Is it true that some kind of "mixed-mode" is possible regarding the programming languages? So that most of the app is written in c# and a small subset of logic is written in c++ to access .dll functionalities that controls a hardware device (from a windows 10 app)?